# How to do iterated moves of items in an array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

Let's say we have an array:

`var scrambledAlphabet = ["B", "C", "D", "E", "H", "F", "G", "A"]`

and we want sort it by moving two items: item 7 ("A") to location 0, and item 4 ("H") to 7, described with an array of tuples:

`var moves = [(7, 0), (4, 7)]`

So, the desired result is:

> ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]

Spontaneous that would be easy solved with this:

```
var scrambledAlphabet = ["B", "C", "D", "E", "H", "F", "G", "A"]
var moves = [(7, 0), (4, 7)]

for (i, j) in moves  {
    scrambledAlphabet.insert(scrambledAlphabet.remove(at: i), at: j)
}
print(scrambledAlphabet)
```

But it doesn't work. The output is:

> ["A", "B", "C", "D", "H", "F", "G", "E"]

The problem is that once the first item is moved, the index of the next item is altered. So, what would be the best way to tackle this? I find this surprisingly hard to crack. Any help is appreciated.

The restriction is that the two variables, `scrambledAlphabet` and `moves`, must be able to grow to any number.

And also one important note, the move-to-index (second number in the tuple) is referring to the old array, **not** the newly created. So, the inputs `["B", "C", "E", "D", "H", "F", "G", "A"]` and `[(7, 0), (4, 7), (3, 2)]` should result in:

> ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]

Sorry about the confusion about this last bit.

Comment: Can you show some more sample inputs and outputs? I want to check if my solution is correct.

Comment: that will not work because once you move object at index 7 to index 0, object at index 4 will no longer be H it will be E and H's index will be 5

Comment: @SandeepBhandari You've pinpointed the problem, so what is the solution?

Comment: @Sweeper The inputs are the variables, please feel free to extend it to the complete alphabet an do 50 predefined moves to see if your solution holds.

Answer (score 1):

I thought of this (IMO a little clumsy) solution:

```
var newArray = Array(repeating: "", count: scrambledLetters.count)
for (start, end) in moves {
    newArray[end] = scrambledLetters[start]
    scrambledLetters[start] = ""
}
var scrambledLetterIndex = -1

func setScrambledLetterIndexToNextNonEmptyString() {
    scrambledLetterIndex += 1
    while scrambledLetterIndex < scrambledLetters.count - 1 && scrambledLetters[scrambledLetterIndex].isEmpty {
        scrambledLetterIndex += 1
    }
}

for i in newArray.indices {
    if newArray[i] == "" {
        setScrambledLetterIndexToNextNonEmptyString()
        newArray[i] = scrambledLetters[scrambledLetterIndex]
    }
}

scrambledLetters = newArray
```

Essentially, I first created a new array, and "took out" the strings that needs to be moved, and placed them in the correct position in the new array. That's what the first for loop did.

After the first for loop, the two arrays will look like this:

```
scrambledLetters:   ["B", "C", "D", "E", "", "F", "G", ""]
newArray:           ["A", "", "", "", "", "", "" , "H"]
```

Then, I slowly copied each non-empty item in the scrambled letters array into the new array's empty places.

Because this solution makes use of the empty string, it won't work if the input domain contained empty strings. If that's the case, you'd have to use something like a `[String?]`.

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach is to use an array of all indices which are *not* the source of any move. Then we can fill the destination sequentially, either from one of the moves, or from one of the “other indices”:

```
func scramble<T>(array: [T], moves: [(Int, Int)]) -> [T] {

    // Moves sorted by increasing destination index:
    var moves = moves.sorted(by: { $0.1 < $1.1 })

    // All indices which are not the source of a move:
    let sourceIndices = Set(moves.map { $0.0 })
    var otherIndices = array.indices.filter { !sourceIndices.contains($0)}

    // Fill each position with an element of a move source,
    // or one of the "other" array elements:
    return array.indices.map {
        if let (from, to) = moves.first, $0 == to {
            moves.removeFirst()
            return array[from]
        } else {
            return array[otherIndices.removeFirst()]
        }
    }
}
```

Example 1:

```
print(scramble(array: ["B", "C", "D", "E", "H", "F", "G", "A"],
               moves:  [(7, 0), (4, 7)]))
// ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]
```

Example 2:

```
print(scramble(array: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
               moves: [(1, 6), (7, 2), (3, 5), (5, 3), (4, 7)]))
// [0, 2, 7, 5, 6, 3, 1, 4]
```

Comment: But with the array `["B", "C", "E", "D", "H", "F", "G", "A"]` and moves `[(7, 0), (4, 7), (3, 2)]` this returns ["A", "B", "D", "C", "E", "F", "G", "H"]

Comment: @turingtested: Yes, it does, and it looks correct to me. Perhaps I misunderstand the task? What result would you expect?

Comment: Expexted: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"], since letter 3 ("D") should move to position 2.

Comment: @turingtested: Sorry, I don't get it. In your expected result the letter "D" is still at position 3 (the indices are zero-based). If the "D" is moved to position 2 then the new array starts with ["A", "B", "D", ... ]

Comment: @turingtested: With the moves `[(7, 0), (4, 7), (3, 3)]` you would get the expected result (the D is “fixed” at position 3).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214763/discussion-between-martin-r-and-turingtested).